# Подключение flask к удаленной read-only postgresql базе данных с помощью sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Можно ли подключиться к удаленной read_only бд постгре через sqlalchemy, не создавая моделей? Ведь я собираюсь только считывать оттуда информацию.
 Или обязательно создавать модели для каждой колонки как в самой БД?

Comment: А зачем вам SQLAlchemy, если моделями пользоваться вы не хотите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать `automap`, тогда алхимия автоматически сгенерирует схему по существующей БД (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html )